# Windows Update Issues on Server Core 2022

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-update, windows-server-2022

I have two DNS servers (Nutanix VMs) running Server Core 2022.  When I attempt to run Windows Updates from Sconfig, I get the following errors:

```
1) All quality updates
2) Recommended quality updates only
3) Feature updates



Select an update category (Blank=Cancel): 1
  Searching for all applicable updates...
  An error occurred:
  Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EFE
  (Press ENTER to continue):

  Available update(s):
  An error occurred:
  Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'Item'.
  (Press ENTER to continue):
```

This started occurring two or three months ago.  This week I deleted both the VMs and rebuilt them from scratch.  Right after the rebuild I was able to run Windows Updates with no problems.  As soon as I got them all configured as DNS servers and back into production, I ran Windows Updates and received the same errors again.  We have another DNS Server Core running Server 2019 and it has no issues.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: 0x80072EFE is generic for issues connecting to update services - Make sure the VMs can resolve (especially as they're both hosting DNS) and connect to http/https update server URLs successfully. Do you have other working 2022 VMs? You might be able to step-by-step through the process using powershell like: https://superuser.com/a/1620950/673426 and see which part fails or if you get a better error than from sconfig

Comment: Can you start an admin powershell prompt and try this: Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate Get-WUInstall -Install - MicrosoftUpdate If you only want to show the updates you can do get-wulist

Comment: Try with the PSWindowsUpdate PowerShell Module

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I was able to ping throughout the network with no issues.  I do have other Sever Core VMs that do windows updates without issue.  They're not running DNS though.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Unfortunately I ran out of patience and rebuilt the two VMs.

Answer (score 0):

I blew away one of these servers and rebuilt it exactly as it had been built originally.  Same VM hardware settings, and built as Server Core with only DNS installed.  The first time I ran Windows Update from sconfig, it crapped out the same way.

Now I've rebuilt both of them as standard Windows GUI servers with DNS installed, and I have no issues running Windows Update.

So, something with the combination of Core Server only with DNS installed was causing the issue.  (???)  Very odd.  I'd like to revisit it one day.